# Appending new content using socket.io and jquery

Tags: jquery, socket.io

I am attempting to get the latest data from my database and append it on my HTML page i am kind of new using `socket.io` and don't know if there's a better way of doing this.

I have this code below on my `server.js` that every time a new instance is executed i will select the latest data from my database and emit it on my `index.html`

```
socket.on('new instance', function (data) {
    var query = con.query("SELECT * FROM sales_agent WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(hour, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')" +
        " > SUBDATE( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) GROUP BY unq",
        function (err, rows, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            for (var i in rows) {
                io.sockets.emit('active charts', {
                    msg: rows[i].product,
                    date: rows[i].date_added,
                    board: rows[i].type
                });
            }
        });
});
```

Now on my index.html when `active charts` is called i will append it into a `div` having a id of `chart_content`

```
var $chart = $('#chart_content');
socket.on('active charts', function (data) {
    console.log('Data instance called');
    $chart.append('<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="card"><div class="body' +
        ' bg-blue-grey">' + data.msg + '  ' + data.board + ' </div></div> </div>');
});
```

Everything works on first load, as expected when i new instance is called, it then again append the same data on my `div` so i have duplicate data inside a `div` I've looked into some jquery methods like `one`, `remove`,`load`,`html`,`replaceWith` to clear the div first but it does not work like i need it to be.

What i am thinking is remove the current content of a div and replace it with a new one using `append`, any advice to achieve this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $chart = $('#chart_content');
var allData = [];

function checkIn(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
        // drop your logic here
        if (allData[i].msg == data.msg || allData[i].board == data.board) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function showData() {
    $chart.empty();
    allData.forEach(function (data) {
        $chart.append('<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="card"><div class="body' +
            ' bg-blue-grey">' + data.msg + '  ' + data.board + ' </div></div> </div>');
    });
}
socket.on('active charts', function (data) {
    console.log('Data instance called');
    if (!checkIn(data)) {
        allData.push(data);
        showData();
    }
});
```

1. create data keeper
2. check data is already exist
3. if not then push
4. empty your chat_content
5. append all data again

does it make scene?

Comment: Thanks sir, that make sense.